# Push view controller when I "click" over uisearchbar

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I want to push a `UIViewController` into the `UINavigationController` when I click over a `UISearchBar`, such that the keyboard does not appear, just open the new view, and when I come back, show some string in the `UISearchBar`.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 yoursearchBar.delegate = yourDelegateObject;
```

Then inside your `yourDelegateObject` Class, have this `UISearchBar` delegate method

```
 - (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{

       // Here write the code to push to new view controller
       return NO;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could place a custom `UIButton` over your `UISearchBar` and push the new `UIViewController` on button press OR you could set your `UIViewController` as the `UISearchBar`[delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007530-CH3-DontLinkElementID_1) and implement [searchBarShouldBeginEditing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UISearchBarDelegate/searchBarShouldBeginEditing%3a), return NO to prevent input and push the `UIViewController` from this "delegate" method. You will also probably need to implement some form of delegation to have your string on coming back to the pushing `UIViewController` in order to populate it in the `UISearchBar`

Answer (score -1):

You can use your custom `UIView` instead of the standard keyboard. Just set in code:

```
UISearchbar *mySearchbar = [[UISearchbar alloc] init];
mySearchbar.inputView = myInputView;
```

If you now tap on the searchbar your `myCustomView` will appear on the bottom of the window (where the keyboard is located usually).